# How do you get a row of buttons in a fixed position?

Tags: java, layout

I have to make a very simple calculator and the buttons(add, subtract, divide and multiply) need to be below the numbers input and results in a fixed position. In the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJkZy.jpg) shows what I should have and on the other side it shows what I currently have.

```
package calculator; 
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;




public class Calculator extends JFrame {
private JTextField Number1TxtField; 
private JTextField Number2TxtField;  
private JTextField ResultTxtField; 
private JButton add; 
private JButton subtract; 
private JButton multiply; 
private JButton divide;



 public Calculator() { // class for the calculator 




        setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT,8,10));
        add(new JLabel("Number 1"));
        Number1TxtField=new JTextField(8); add(Number1TxtField);
        add(new JLabel("Number 2"));
        Number2TxtField=new JTextField(8);
        Number2TxtField=new JTextField(8); add(Number2TxtField);
        add(new JLabel("Result"));
        ResultTxtField= new JTextField(8); add(ResultTxtField);
        ResultTxtField.setEditable(false); add(ResultTxtField);




        //new JPanel
        add = new JButton("Add"); add(add);

        subtract = new JButton ("Subtract"); add(subtract);

        multiply = new JButton ("Multiply"); add(multiply);

        divide = new JButton ("Divide"); add(divide);


        ButtonListener btnlistener = new ButtonListener ();

        add.addActionListener(btnlistener);

        subtract.addActionListener(btnlistener);

        multiply.addActionListener(btnlistener);

        divide.addActionListener(btnlistener);
    }

class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

      @Override

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

String num1str = Number1TxtField.getText();

double num1 = Double.parseDouble(num1str );

String num2str = Number2TxtField.getText();

double num2 = Double.parseDouble(num2str );

double result;

      if (e.getSource() == add)
          result = num1+num2;

      else if (e.getSource() == subtract)
    result = num1-num2;

      else if (e.getSource() == multiply)
    result = num1*num2;

      else //DivideButton
    result = num1/num2;


ResultTxtField.setText(String.valueOf(result));

  }
    }



        public static void main(String[] args) { 



        Calculator frame = new Calculator(); 

        frame.setTitle("Calculator");  

        frame.setSize(600,120);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setVisible(true); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create two panel: `topPanel` and  `buttonsPanel`. Add your buttons to the `buttonsPanel` and add this panel to the `CENTER` position of the `JFrame`. Then add your textfields to the `topPanel` and put `topPanel` to the NORTH position of the `JFrame`.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Calculator extends JFrame {
    private JTextField Number1TxtField;
    private JTextField Number2TxtField;
    private JTextField ResultTxtField;
    private JButton add;
    private JButton subtract;
    private JButton multiply;
    private JButton divide;

    public Calculator() { // class for the calculator

        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();

        topPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 8, 5));
        topPanel.add(new JLabel("Number 1"));
        Number1TxtField = new JTextField(5);
        topPanel.add(Number1TxtField);
        topPanel.add(new JLabel("Number 2"));
        Number2TxtField = new JTextField(5);
        topPanel.add(Number2TxtField);
        topPanel.add(new JLabel("Result"));
        ResultTxtField = new JTextField(8);
        topPanel.add(ResultTxtField);
        ResultTxtField.setEditable(false);
        topPanel.add(ResultTxtField);

        // new JPanel
        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonsPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 8, 5));
        add = new JButton("Add");
        buttonsPanel.add(add);

        subtract = new JButton("Subtract");
        buttonsPanel.add(subtract);

        multiply = new JButton("Multiply");
        buttonsPanel.add(multiply);

        divide = new JButton("Divide");
        buttonsPanel.add(divide);

        ButtonListener btnlistener = new ButtonListener();

        add.addActionListener(btnlistener);

        subtract.addActionListener(btnlistener);

        multiply.addActionListener(btnlistener);

        divide.addActionListener(btnlistener);

        getContentPane().add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        getContentPane().add(buttonsPanel);
    }

    class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String num1str = Number1TxtField.getText();

            double num1 = Double.parseDouble(num1str);

            String num2str = Number2TxtField.getText();

            double num2 = Double.parseDouble(num2str);

            double result;

            if (e.getSource() == add)
                result = num1 + num2;

            else if (e.getSource() == subtract)
                result = num1 - num2;

            else if (e.getSource() == multiply)
                result = num1 * num2;

            else // DivideButton
                result = num1 / num2;

            ResultTxtField.setText(String.valueOf(result));

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Calculator frame = new Calculator();

        frame.setTitle("Calculator");

        frame.pack();

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```